# How do I draw text into a subview?

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I want to draw text into `UIView`'s subview using `drawInRect:withFont:lineBreakMode` call but that operates on the current context only.

Is it possible to draw text into a subview from current view?

The subview is a generic `UIView` instance and I don't really want to create a new `UIView`-derived class just for this purpose if I can avoid it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to add a CALayer to the view's layer instead of adding a UIView to the view.  The CALayer has a `delegate` property which you can assign any object to.  The CALayer calls:

```
- (void)drawLayer:(CALayer *)layer inContext:(CGContextRef)ctx
```

on the `delegate`, which you can take to do something like:

```
- (void)drawLayer:(CALayer *)layer inContext:(CGContextRef)ctx {
    if (layer == myLayer) {
        UIGraphicsPushContext(ctx);
        [string drawInRect:rect withFont:font lineBreakMode:mode];
        UIGraphicsPopContext();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, if you're going to do something with a context, you have to be in that view's -drawRect:. You can always make your subview a UIView subclass that overrides -drawRect: to display the text you want... but at that point, you're kind of reinventing UILabel.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do what you describe. Subclassing UIView is exactly the method you're supposed to use for this— there's nothing wrong with creating a UIView subclass which only has a simple `-drawRect:` method.